# How do I use pygame-menu as a settings menu for a pygame program?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-menu

I am making a pygame program and decided to use the pygame-menu library for some easy gui for the settings menu. Every example I can find uses the menu as the whole program, making it hard to figure out how to add a menu to a pygame program.

Every time I run the following code, I get an error:

```py
import pygame
import pygame_menu

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
scrn_size = pygame.display.Info()
scrn = pygame.display.set_mode((scrn_size.current_w, scrn_size.current_h), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

rotation_menu = pygame_menu.Menu(
    'Rotation',
    1000, 800,
    onclose=pygame_menu.events.BACK
)

speed_values_discrete = {0: 'Stopped', 2: '', 5: '', 10: '', 20: '', 30: 'Fastest'}
rotate_speed_range = rotation_menu.add.range_slider('Speed', 5, list(speed_values_discrete.keys()),
    slider_text_value_enabled=False,
    value_format=lambda x: speed_values_discrete[x]
)


menu = pygame_menu.Menu(
    'Configuration',
    1000, 800,
    enabled=False,
    onclose=pygame_menu.events.CLOSE
)

menu.add.button('Rotation', rotation_menu)
menu.add.button('Colors')


def main():
    rotation = 0
    rpf = 5
    move = False
    x, y = 0, 0
    pos = (0, 0)
    img_size = 300
    img = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('img.png'), (img_size, img_size))

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT or (e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_q):
                pygame.quit()
                exit(1)
            elif e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                menu.enable()
            elif e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and move:
                pos = e.pos
                x = pos[0] - (img_size / 2)
                y = pos[1] - (img_size / 2)

        scrn.fill((0, 0, 0))
        rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(img, rotation)
        rotation += rpf
        new_rect = rotated.get_rect(center=img.get_rect(topleft=(x, y)).center)
        scrn.blit(rotated, new_rect)

        if menu.is_enabled():
            menu.update(events)
            menu.draw(scrn)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zer0\Documents\Spinner\main.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Zer0\Documents\Spinner\main.py", line 73, in main
    menu.draw(scrn)
  File "C:\Users\Zer0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygame_menu\menu.py", line 2053, in draw
    self._current._runtime_errors.throw(self._current._runtime_errors.draw, 'menu is not enabled')
  File "C:\Users\Zer0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pygame_menu\menu.py", line 4090, in throw
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: menu is not enabled
```

The program should spin an image. When you click the screen, a settings menu opens. You can go to sub-menus like rotation settings and change those. A problem I have is how do I change the rotation speed variable (`rpf`) with the `RangeSlider` in the rotation settings menu? (This Issue Is Not Solved)

Another problem I have is when I close out of the menus, I get the error above, stating that the menu is not enabled. This is confusing because the function has to pass through a check to see if it is enabled, which it did. Then it instantly has a problem because it is not enabled! This is frustrating. (This Issue Is Solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `menu.update()` might disable the menu. This happens when you click on the cross at the top right of the menu. Therefore you have to check if the menu is enabled with `menu.is_enabled()` before drawing the menu with `menu.draw(scrn)`:

```py
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for e in events:
        # [...]

        elif e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            menu.enable()

    # [...]

    if menu.is_enabled():
        menu.update(events)

    if menu.is_enabled():
        menu.draw(scrn)
```

Comment: this solved the error, thanks! all I need now, is how to change the "rpf" variable with the range slider